# How to use the WordPress wp_mail(); function on an external PHP using Advanced Email Options settings e.g. WP-Mail-SMTP Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, web

How to use the WordPress `wp_mail();` function on a custom external PHP page using Advanced Email Options saved connection settings.

Furthermore the PHP page is hosted in `/wp-content/wpmailtest.php`

I would like to know if this is possible and if so, I would like a brief explanation.

By the way **example@example.com** is not my email and has been changed for the example below:-

```
include '../wp-load.php';

$to = 'example@example.com';
$subject = 'The subject';
$body = 'The email body content';
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

wp_mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Moreover The mail is not sent. But my saved settings work when i do a send test in the wp-admin page in "Advanced Email Options" e.g. WP-Mail-SMTP Plugin--->Settings, run email test.

Comment: Did you want to say that you want to use wp_mail() in custom php file?

Comment: Yes that is correct, within a custom php file.

Comment: I just try this code in my local and it's working fine. please cross check again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
include '../../../wp-load.php';
```

include this file in your custom php file on the top. then after you can access all wordpress functions inside that file. including `wp_mail()` function.

Comment: Now i'm getting HTTP ERROR 500. The page is hosted in /wp-content/wpmailtest.php furthermore the page was loading before adding the following line.

Comment: In your case you should replace with below code 
include '../wp-load.php';.

Comment: Ok, page now loads but the email is not sent. But works when i do a send test in the wp-admin page in "Advanced Email Options" run email test.

Comment: Could you please let me know what you mean by "Advanced Email Options" ?

Comment: WP-Mail-SMTP Plugin--->Settings

Comment: Checked my email had a spelling error. It now works and thank you for the information you have given.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111785/discussion-between-mattlinux1-and-purvik7373).

Comment: sure we can continue this conversation in chat.